# Document sniffing via Load<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I'm using RavenDb with ASP.NET Web Api and i've noticed, that it's possible to query other documents with the `Load<Type>` method.

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    /* Other properties */
}

public class Pet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public Person FindById(string id)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = _docStore.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Load<Person>(id);
    }
}
```

If i call FindById("pets/13") via ajax on the web api method, i'm getting back a Person object with the Pet's entity data, because they share common properties. How can i avoid that? This could expose confidential data to the attackers.

Even if the properties don't match, an object with null properties is returned exposing the existance of the entity with the given id.

My current workaround for this is:

```
[HttpGet]
public Person FindById(string id)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = _docStore.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Load<Person>("people/" + id.Split('/')[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use guids for your ids?

Comment: @levelnis That's curing a symptom, not the problem

Comment: Yes, but if your concern is that attackers might compromise your data by intercepting calls and manipulating ids, the chances of them getting the correct guid are exceptionally slim at best

Answer (score 1):

IDs are unique across documents. Don't abuse that: you're calling session.Load<Person>, but you're passing in an ID for a Pet. Don't do that.

Internally, Raven is probably doing something like this:

1. "find a JSON document with id = 'pets/13'"
2. Got it! Now, turn that JSON document into...uh...the developer asked for a Person.
3. It kinda-sorta works as a Person. Return that, since the developer told us to.

Basically, you told Raven to return a Person, and it did the best it could, by turning the Pet JSON document into a Person object, which is exactly what you told it to do.

If you're concerned of malicious use of your FindById method, just throw an exception if the ID isn't for a Person object:

```
[HttpGet]
public Person FindById(string id)
{
    // We're concerned someone might call FindById and fish for non-Person objects.
    if (!id.StartsWith("people/"))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Naughty!");
    }

    using (IDocumentSession session = _docStore.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Load<Person>(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website section 'routes':

> The easiest way to get around this is to have your controllers use the version of session.Load<>() accepting an integer. This function will automatically translate the integer value to the fully qualified document ID, and then use it to perform the load operation.

```
public ActionResult Read(int id)
{
    var obj = RavenSession.Load<MyClass>(id);
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this doesn't work in the latest client of RavenDb with string id-s. It just returns back a null.

Comment: Looking at the code: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Client.Lightweight/Document/DocumentSession.cs line 263, it should work. The id parameter must be an integer.

Comment: I tried this in a console application and it works. Code is here: http://pastebin.com/tby97e7a

Comment: if you don't need to use string for id, you can use int. This will result in the same id in raven (pets/123) but in your model it will always be int.

Comment: Can't unfortunately, this resulted in int32 formatting exceptions in static indices.